# Minimal number of swaps and inserts/removes of digits to transform number to another number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, numbers

So I have the following task:
Given two numbers N and K. We can perform

- add digit at the end of the number.
- remove digit from the end of the number.
- swap two digits in a number.

I need to write a function that return the minimal number of operations to be performed to transform N to K.

```
f(1234, 4326) = 4 // 1234 (swap)-> 4231 (swap)-> 4321 (remove)-> 432 (insert)->4326
```

The task is given as homework to "Introduction to programming" course, so no dynamic programming (which was my solution), no data structures (as stacks, queues) are allowed.

The teacher said that there is a simple solution with no extra memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could run a greedy algorithm but it won't always result in an optimal solution. IMHO, whatever heuristic you choose, there are counter examples to disprove it. Unless there are other constraints that you haven't mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: Actually, it's `4` operations, not `3`.  You do `2` swaps, `1` remove and `1` insert.

Comment: Could you post your dynamic programming solution? A greedy solution is probably the expected answer, although that uses O(1) memory rather than 'no extra' memory.